# Пропадает целочисленная часть у десятичного числа при конкатенации полей

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Конкатенирую два поля с десятичным числом и текстом. В выгрузке отдельно это поле отображается корректно, а в поле с конкатенацией только знак перед числом и его десятичная часть.

мой код:

```
select
  DMTR."Коэфф.",
  DMTR."Позиция",
  DMTR."Коэфф." || ', Поз - ' ||  DMTR."Позиция" as INF
from
  table1 DMTR
where 
  DMTR."Дата " > TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1)
```

[image: что я получаю]

куда пропадают нули до разделителя в поле INF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> куда пропадают нули до разделителя в поле INF?

Не поверишь - но вот именно так выполняется преобразование числа в строку (явное или неявное), если не указывать формат.

Так что надо преобразовать явно, и с указанием нужного формата. См. [Format Models: Number Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211).

Например, так:

```sql
select
  to_char(DMTR."Коэфф.", '90.99') as "Коэфф.",
  DMTR."Позиция",
  to_char(DMTR."Коэфф.", '90.99') || ', Поз - ' || DMTR."Позиция" as INF
from
  table1 DMTR
where 
  DMTR."Дата " > TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1)
```

Comment: @Mnk Кстати, странно, что у тебя в колонке "Коэфф." числа с ведущим нулём - при чистом SELECT Оракл должен был их порезать. Вероятно, это твой клиент расстарался при отображении числа, добавил ведущие нули... а вот со строковым полем он этого, само собой, делать не стал.